# ¿Cómo mostrar los datos seleccionados de una opción múltiple mediante JSON?

Tags: php, html, ajax, json

De esta manera he realizado mi `HTML`, en el que aparece la opción múltiple:

```
<body>

    <div id="contenedor">

        <br/><br/>
        <label>DNI</label>
        <input type="text" id="dni"> 

        <br/><br/>
        <label>NOMBRE</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre"> 

        <br/><br/>
        <label>APELLIDO</label>
        <input type="text" id="apellido"> 

        <br/><br/>
        <label>CELULAR</label>
        <input type="text" id="numero">
        <br/><br/><br/>

        <select class="test" id="tecnologia" name="tecnologia[]" multiple="multiple">
            <option>2G</option> 
            <option>3G</option> 
            <option>4G</option> 
            <option>TDD</option>
        </select>

        </br></br><br/><br/>
        <button onclick="anadir();">Añadir</button>

        <input type="submit" onclick="buscar()" value="buscar">

    </div>

</body>
```

Los datos seleccionados en la opción múltiple (`$tecnologia`) los guardo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

    include("conexion.php");

    $dni        = $_POST['dni_cli'];
    $nombre     = $_POST['nom_cli'];
    $apellido   = $_POST['ape_cli'];
    $numero     = $_POST['num_cli'];    
    $tecnologia = implode('\r\n', $_POST['tecnologia']);

    $query = $mysql->query("INSERT INTO clie (dni, nombre, apellido, numero, tecnologia) VALUES ('$dni', '$nombre', '$apellido', '$numero', '$tecnologia')");

    if ($query) {
        echo "se añadio correctamente";
    } else {
        echo "ya existe el dni " . $dni;
    }

?>
```

Entonces lo que busco es que al momento de llamar de la base de datos, me muestre en la opción múltiple los datos que fueron seleccionados (o sea, que me los muestre marcados como en un inicio).

Mediante `Ajax` realizo la función `buscar`:

```
function buscar () {

    var parametros = {"dni" : $("#dni").val(),}

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '../lunes-2/buscardatos.php',
        data: parametros,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (d) {
            $("#nombre").val(d[0]);
            $("#apellido").val(d[1]);
            $("#numero").val(d[2]);
            // aquí iría el código (así como para nombre, apellido y número)
            // para poder llamar a los datos de la opcion multiple
            // que recibo de MySQL
        }
    });

}
```

Esta función hará llamar los valores de la base de datos en formato `JSON`, que lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("archivos", $con);

    $dni = $_POST["dni"];
    $rs  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clie WHERE dni='$dni'");

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
    $datos_a_enviar = array($row['nombre'], $row['apellido'], $row['numero'], $row['tecnologia']);
    echo json_encode($datos_a_enviar);    
?>
```

Comment: que valores trae $row['tecnologia']

Comment: lo que $row['tecnologia'] traeria serian los datos que estan almacenados en el mysql. por ejemplo: si en el index selecciono 2G y 3G ,traeria esos valores, y entonces al momento d ingrear DNI y dar en "buscar", me mostraria el 2G y 3G seleccionados

Comment: Has inpseccionado la variable d cuando regresa tu funcion Ajax?

Comment: claro, anteriormente habia realizado la misma funcion, pero en vez de que regrese una opcion multiple me regrese un checkbox marcado, y si retornaba valores normalmente

Comment: Ten en cuenta que tu código `php` es vulnerable a [inyecciones SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). Te recomendaría que [escaparas](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php) los datos que recibes de `JavaScript` o  que utilices en vez de `mysql_query`, [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/intro.pdo.php) para manipular la base de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primero que nada deberias establecer valores para option de tu multiselect
algo asi:**

```
<select class="test" id="tecnologia" name="tecnologia[]" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="2g">2G</option> 
   <option value="3g">3G</option> 
   <option value="4g">4G</option> 
   <option value="tdd">TDD</option>
</select>
```

**este es un ejemplo de valores** 
seleccion en tu ajax suponiendo que tu resultado trae algo asi:

```
var values="2g,3g,4g";
```

**el recorrido del resultado lo harias asi:**

```
$.each(values.split(","), function(i,e){
    $("#strings option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
});
```

ese es un ejemplo, debes ver que datos traes desde tu db y en base a eso establecer el selected..suerte !!
[Link Probado](https://jsfiddle.net/hL2jt9n0/3/)

Comment: claro, en el mysql se guardan los valores separados por comas, y luego son llamadas.

Comment: en este caso tengo solo 4 opciones(2g,3g,4g,tdd),pero si tuviera 100 valores, y selecciono el primero, el vigesimo y el ultimo; ¿como haria para que de los 100 valores que tengo me muestre los "valores selecionados" como los primeros de la lista?

Comment: @kevincallupesantillan lo que hace la funcion que detalle en mi rspuesta es recorrer el resultado y comparar si el valor retornado es igual al de la option y si lo es lo establece como selected, no importa si son 4, 10 , 100 siempre verifica si el resultado de tu db es igual al valor de cada option de tu multiselect

Comment: @kevincallupesantillan, para lo que deseas hacer de que las opciones seleccionadas sean las primeras en la lista, creo que lo mejor es que elabores otra pregunta. Ya esta ha sido respondida, puedes encontrar más ayuda si creas una nueva. Un saludo ;)

Answer (score 1):

Si tu `select` múltiple puede tener un número grande de opciones, puedes hacer que el código sea más [eficiente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eficiencia_Algor%C3%ADtmica) utilizando una técnica similar a la que he mecionado en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934669/how-can-i-validate-the-input-from-a-html5-datalist/49084576#49084576) de SOen: creas un [hash map](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabla_hash) con las opciones **al inicio de tu aplicación** y solo accedes a la propiedad correcta de dicho `hash map` para variar la propiedad `selected`. Por otro lado, en vez de realizar el *split* de los valores en `JavaScript`, lo podrías hacer en el servidor, de esta manera te llegaría ya un `array` listo para iterar en vez de una cadena que tienes que manipular:

> Como te comentaba @alanfcm, lo mejor es que guardes tu lista en la base de datos separándola por algún tipo de caracter como una coma o un *pipe*. Para el ejemplo supondré que los datos están separados por comas.

**PHP**

```
$datos_a_enviar = array($row['nombre'], $row['apellido'], $row['numero'], explode(',', $row['tecnologia']));
echo json_encode($datos_a_enviar);
```

**Código JavaScript para conformar el hash de opciones:**

```
// Al inicio de tu aplicación crear un hash map con las opciones
var opciones = Array.prototype.reduce.call(document.getElementById("tecnologia").options, function (obj, opt) {
    obj[opt.value] = opt;
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Este código conformará un objeto que tendrá la siguiente estructura:

```
{
    "2G" : [option element],
    "3G" : [option element],
    "4G" : [option element],
    ...
    ...
}
```

Por lo tanto si te hace falta seleccionar la opción que tiene el texto `3G`, lo único que debes hacer es situar:

```
opciones["3G"].selected = true;
```

Esto es mucho más eficiente, ya que no tienes que recorrer todas las opciones buscando la opción que tenga un valor determinado (cada vez que creas un selector de `jQuery` tomando como referencia su valor, `jQuery` recorrerá el `DOM` intentando buscar dicho elemento).

Sabiendo esto, puedes utilizar el `array` de valores que recibes por `Ajax` para actualizar las opciones correctas:

**Código JavaScript de la función de success:**

```
// En el success del Ajax
success: function (d) {

    $("#nombre").val(d[0]);
    $("#apellido").val(d[1]);
    $("#numero").val(d[2]);

    // Seleccionar las opciones
    d[3].forEach(function (val) {
        if (opciones[val]) {
            opciones[val].selected = true;
        }
    });     

}
```

Comment: function buscar(){

    var parametros={"dni": $("#dni").val(),}
    $.ajax({

            type: 'post',
            url: '../lunes-2/buscardatos.php',
            data: parametros,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(d){
                $("#nombre").val(d[0]);
                $("#apellido").val(d[1]);
                $("#numero").val(d[2]);
               

            }
        });
} pero estoy usando la variable parametros, crearia otra variable?

Comment: @kevincallupesantillan, no entiendo bien tu pregunta. ¿A qué te refieres?

Comment: en la funcion buscar estoy usando un VAR  llamado parametros, pero tu dices que trabaje con un VAR opciones, lo reemplazo o lo pongo como un segundo VAR? y al momento de llamar en el AJAX(si es que pongo los dos VAR)....¿como pondria en el DATA?¿data:parametros,opciones,?

Comment: No, el `hash` de opciones lo debes poner al inicio de tu aplicación (fuera de toda la lógica de buscar y del `Ajax`). Este `hash` guarda todas tus opciones en un objeto tomando como clave el valor de las mismas, de esta manera cada vez que te haga falta activar o desactivar alguna no tienes que recorrer todas las opciones para hacerlo, solo tienes que acceder a la opción con la propiedad deseada. Voy a añadir esto a la respuesta porque parece que no queda claro.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que sería más fácil que guardaras los valores separados por comas así:

```
$tecnologia = implode(',', $_POST['tecnologia']);
```

Y luego para seleccionar los valores lo harías así:

```
success: function (d) {
    $("#nombre").val(d[0]);
    $("#apellido").val(d[1]);
    $("#numero").val(d[2]);
    $.each(d[3].split(","), function(i, e) {
        $("#tecnologia option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
    });
}
```

Comment: en este caso tengo solo 4 opciones(2g,3g,4g,tdd),pero si tuviera 100 valores, y selecciono el primero, el vigesimo y el ultimo; ¿como haria para que de los 100 valores que tengo me muestre los "valores selecionados" como los primeros de la lista?

Comment: Creo que la unica forma seria rehacer el select con las primeras opciones como las seleccionadas.  Otra opcion seria usar un plugin como Select2